# What is terminal state in gridworld?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov, markov-decision-process

I am learning markov decision process.
Am I don't know where to mark terminal states.

In 4x3 grid world, I marked the terminal state that I think correct(I might be wrong) with T.
[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c1CD.png)

I saw an instruction mark terminal states as follow.

```
terminals=[(3, 2), (3, 1)]
```

Can someone explain how does it work?

Comment: [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to ask theoretical questions related to reinforcement learning, so I suggest that you ask your question there (and, definitely, next time you have a question about RL, you should ask it there). If you ask it there, please, delete it from here (to avoid cross-posting, which is generally discouraged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given grid-world, you start at "start" which is (0,0). Then you move around from that point. If you reach at "end +1"{(3,2)} then the reward is +1 and the game ends. Likewise, if you reach at "end -1"{(3,1)} then the reward is -1 and the game ends. However, while you are moving around, you can't move to {(1,1)} as its invalid state. Also, if you reach any of the terminal state "T" which are at {(2,0) and(2,1)} then the game ends with zero reward.